# How can I convert/change JSON value?

Tags: java, json, gson

I changed the structure JSON files. I must change the value of a lot JSONs objects. Manually change to do their reading would take me a long time.

For example I have:

```
"Domain" {
"id": 0,
"name": "Domain of service",
"desc": "Registered service",
"conf": {
     "us": {
         "name": "US SP"
         "icon": "us.png"
        }
   "plsl": {
         "name": "PLSL SP"
         "icon": "plsl.png"
    }
 }
```

I want to this:

```
"Info": "Domain of service",
"rTypeID": "0",
"rTypeCode": "Domain",
"Name": "Domain of service",
"Description": "Registered service",
"RepositoryObject": [ {
"rCode:" "us",
"name:" "US PA",
"description:" "",
"sValue:" "us.png"
"rCode:" "plsl",
"name:" "PLSL PA",
"description:" "",
"sValue:" "plsl.png"
```

For example, I want change `"id":` to `"rTypeID"`, `"desc"` to `"Description":`, `"icon":` to `"sValue:"`.

I heard that easily do it using the library GSON. Thanks for help.

Comment: please attach your java class. What is the library currently used? are you parsing from or to json

Comment: What is the bean for the JSON. Please attach the bean.

Comment: The answers to the linked question describe various methods to translate JSON from one schema to another.  They can be applied to your particular problem.  (It is "just programming")